# Huawei: Configuring netstream

Tags: netflow, huawei

I'm trying to configure NETSTREAM, but I'm a little confused. Following this tutorials: [Configuring NetStream export](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCVHB_1.1.1/device_configure/cnpi_configure_flow_on_huawei_devices.html) and [Huawei:  NetStream Configuration](http://support.huawei.com/enterprise/docinforeader!loadDocument1.action?contentId=DOC1000019448&partNo=10022#dc_cfg_netstream_0011).

I'm configuring netstream on `Huawei Ne20e`

**Global Configurations:**

```
ip netstream export source x.x.x.x 
ip nestream export host x.x.x.x port
```

Explaining what I did, the `source` command I configured the **Huawei ip address** and `host` command the **PRTG ip address udp port** to receive the flows.

After this I'm configuring on a specific interface to send netstream

```
interface Gigabitethernet 0/3/3
ip netstream inbound
ip netstream outbound
```

Is there any for debugging this problem and find a solution? Is the first time I'm configuring it!

Updating:

Revising PRTG material, I saw that there are no native Huawei Sensors available in PRTG. But I want to certify me, there isn't miss command